# Is there a page listing the founding date and the "out of beta" date for all Stack Exchange communities?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, data-explorer, statistics, beta-phase

Just out of curiosity I would like to see a list of all Stack Exchange communities along with the founding date and "out of beta" date.

If the list can be generated using a query, that would be even better.  Some other fields to include in the query would be the number of users and the number of questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created a page on [my personal testing site](https://happy1234.azurewebsites.net/Home/SESites), implementing @Glorfindel's solution of merging the output from `https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/sites?pagesize=999` with the raw HTML from [`https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list`](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list):

- All code is using Javascript plus the jQuery library and the [ag-Grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/) library for display.
- I use AJAX to retrieve both sites, but since there is a CORS restriction on `stackexchange.com` I cache the HTML as a [blob in my personal storage](https://infxpersonal.blob.core.windows.net/data/stackexchange_com_sites.html).
- ASP.NET Core MVC is used for a simple wrapper.

Here's the page: **https://happy1234.azurewebsites.net/Home/SESites**

*Planned future improvements* (please comment for other items you would like to see):

- Move the joining logic to an [Azure Function](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-ca/services/functions/) rather than currently having the page to do heavy-duty jQuery parsing.  Grid will then load faster.
- Instead of storing the whole HTML in the blob, store the grid data instead: much smaller, and reduce Azure bandwidth charge.
- Schedule the Azure Function to run hourly which does everything, thus also minimizing the hits on Stack Exchange API (which has a quota of 300 hits per IP address per day)
- Convert the page into a simple single-page HTML and post it to my github
- Post the Azure function on the github as well

Here's the code:

```html
<div id="errMsg" style="color:red"></div>

NOTES:<br />
<ul>
    <li>Statistics cached as of <span id="cacheddate"></span></li>
    <li>All columns are sortable, resizable, and movable</li>
    <li>Name and State columns are filterable</li>
</ul>

<div id="myGrid" style="height: 600px; width:1070px;" class="ag-theme-alpine"></div>
```

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    retrieveSitesHtml();
});

function retrieveSitesHtml() {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: "html",
        url: "https://infxpersonal.blob.core.windows.net/data/stackexchange_com_sites.html"
    })
        .done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            $("#cacheddate").text(jqXHR.getResponseHeader("last-modified"));
            retrieveSites(data);
        })
        .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $("#errMsg").text("Error reading https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list: " + textStatus);
        });
}

function retrieveSites(siteshtml) {
    // this is called by the done() callback of retrieveSitesHtml()
    return $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/sites?pagesize=999"
    })
        .done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            displaySites(joinData(siteshtml, data.items));
        })
        .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $("#errMsg").text("Error from StackExchange API: " + textStatus);
        });
}

function joinData(siteshtml, sitesapi) {
    // generate grid data by joining sites with info from sitesapi, thus excluding meta sites
    // matching is based on site_url (of sitesapi) with a href (of siteshtml)
    html = $.parseHTML(siteshtml);
    var sites = [];
    sitesapi.forEach(function (o) {
        var site2 = $(html).find(".lv-item a[href='" + o.site_url + "']");
        if (site2.length > 0) {
            site2 = $(site2).parent();
            var site = new Object();
            site.name = o.name.replaceAll("&amp;", "&");
            site.site_url = o.site_url;
            site.state = (o.site_state == "normal") ? "Launched" : "Beta";
            site.launch_date = o.launch_date;
            site.open_beta_date = o.open_beta_date;
            site.questions = Number($(site2).find("input[name='questions']").attr("value"));
            site.users = Number($(site2).find("input[name='users']").attr("value"));
            site.visitsperday = Number($(site2).find("input[name='visits-per-day']").attr("value"));
            sites.push(site);
        }
    });
    return sites;
}

function displaySites(gridData) {
    // this is called by the done() callback of retrieveSites()
    // Set up ag Grid, using:
    //    - a cell renderer for name (to include url)
    //    - value formatters for date and for number
    //    - value getter to add automatic row number that is sensitive to sort & filter change
    var columnDefs = [
        { headerName: "#", pinned: "left", width: 65, valueGetter: "node.rowIndex + 1" },
        { headerName: "Name", field: "name", width: 300, filter: true, cellRenderer: nameRenderer },
        { headerName: "State", field: "state", width: 100, filter: true },
        { headerName: "Launch Date", field: "launch_date", width: 130, valueFormatter: dateFormatter },
        { headerName: "Beta Date", field: "open_beta_date", width: 130, valueFormatter: dateFormatter },
        { headerName: "# Quest", field: "questions", width: 110, valueFormatter: numberFormatter },
        { headerName: "# Users", field: "users", width: 110, valueFormatter: numberFormatter },
        { headerName: "# Visits/day", field: "visitsperday", width: 110, valueFormatter: numberFormatter }
    ];

    // let the grid know which columns and what data to use
    var gridOptions = {
        columnDefs: columnDefs,
        rowData: gridData,
        defaultColDef: {
            resizable: true,
            sortable: true,
            filter: false
        },
        onFilterChanged: function (e) { e.api.refreshCells() },
        onSortChanged: function (e) { e.api.refreshCells() }
    };
    var gridDiv = document.querySelector('#myGrid');
    new agGrid.Grid(gridDiv, gridOptions);
}

function nameRenderer(param) {
    return '<a target="_blank" href="' + param.data.site_url + '">' + param.value + '</a>';
}
function dateFormatter(param) {
    var de = param.value;
    if (de === undefined) return "";
    const monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
    var d = new Date(0);
    d.setUTCSeconds(de);
    return d.getUTCDate() + '-' + monthNames[d.getUTCMonth()] + '-' + d.getUTCFullYear();
}
function numberFormatter(param) {
    var n = param.value;
    return Math.floor(n).toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '$1,');
}
```

Comment: +100, that is awesome.

Comment: @ShadowWizardisVaccinating Thanks a lot for the bounty.  Let me know how I can improve it more.

Comment: I have no idea, not using it myself. Bounty is for the efforts you put into it. Well done!

Answer (score 9):

The dates can be found via the [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites#pagesize=500&filter=!*L1%29CiPaPuKvdX9P&run=true):

[image]

You normally would need to paginate (the API returns at most 100 records at once) but they've made an exception for this particular method.

For the number of questions and users, you can visit the [list of sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questions) and hover over the columns to see the exact amount:

[image]

That means you can write some <s>JavaScript</s> jQuery to extract the information *en masse*. SEDE would work too, but it less reliable as it refreshes only once a week on Sunday morning. But for an estimate, it works fine.

Comment: Thanks @rene. That was about pagination, but while writing that I realized `/sites` has an increased page size. I *didn't* realize I already started writing something :)

Comment: While @rene's answer is more complete (with sample code), I would go with @Glorfindel's idea of fusing the output of `/sites` with the info from the [All Sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list) page.  Preliminary analysis shows that it's quite straightforward to extract the # of questions, etc. stored in hidden `<input>` tags under `<div class="site-bubble">` nodes using jQuery loading the page through Ajax.

Comment: The [API doc](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites) said that we can add the `pagesize` parameter, and I found by default only 30 sites are returned, so I simply add 999.

Answer (score 8):

You can build such list starting with the [`/sites`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites) endpoint already offered by [Glorfindel](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/358672/158100). For each site, you then call the [`/info`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/info)  endpoint to get the number of question, answers and users.

I've made the script to only load 15 sites (that is both main and meta sites) at once. You have to click the Load button to fetch the next 15 sites and so on. This is to reduce to load on the API and to prevent being throttled too much.

```js
(function() {
  var sites = document.getElementById('sites');
  var posturl = '';
  var backoff = 1;
  var queue = [];

  function buildUrl(api, query) {
    var qs = Object.keys(query || {})
      .reduce((acc, val) => {
        return (acc === '' ? '?' + val : acc + '&' + val) + '=' + query[val]
      }, '');
    return 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/' + api + qs;
  }

  function error(txt) {
    document.getElementById('error').textContent = txt;
  }

  function statusUpdate(text) {
    document.getElementById('status').textContent = text;
  }

  function callApi(api, query, reqBody) {
    query.key = 'QGv6M2Kx2ftIozePLXl6nA((';

    function exec(resolve, reject) {

      function handleFetch(url, init, resolve) {
        fetch(url, init).then((data) => {
          if (!data.ok) error(data.status);
          data.json().then((data) => {

            backoff = (data.backoff || 1);
            resolve(data.items); // local resolve
            next();
          });
        });
      }

      function next() {
        setTimeout(() => {
          var item = queue.shift();
          if (item !== undefined) {
            handleFetch(item.url, item.init, item.resolve);
          }
        }, backoff * 1000);
      }

      var init = {};
      if (reqBody !== undefined) {
        init.method = 'POST';
        init.body = new FormData();
        Object.keys(reqBody).forEach((v) => {
          init.body.set(v, reqBody[v]);
        });
        Object.keys(query).forEach((v) => {
          init.body.set(v, query[v]);
        });
        query = {};
      }
      queue.push({
        url: buildUrl(api, query),
        init: init,
        resolve: resolve
      });
      if (queue.length === 1) next();
    }
    return new Promise(exec);
  }

  function getSites(page) {
    return callApi('sites', {
      page: (page || 1),
      filter: '!2*nS2udIcg4I7J2(rArsH'
    });
  }

  function createLink(id) {
    var linkdiv = document.createElement('div');
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = posturl + '/questions/' + id;
    a.textContent = id;
    a.target = '_blank';
    linkdiv.appendChild(a);
    return linkdiv;
  }

  var ta = document.createElement('textarea');

  function makeHtml(raw) {
    ta.innerHTML = raw;
    return ta.textContent;
  }

  function appendInfoRow(info, id) {
    function buildCell(text) {
      var td = document.createElement('td');
      td.textContent = text;
      return td;
    }
    var tr = document.getElementById(id);
    tr.appendChild(buildCell(info.total_questions));
    tr.appendChild(buildCell(info.total_answers));
    tr.appendChild(buildCell(info.total_users));
  }

  function formatDate(serial) {
    if (typeof(serial) !== 'number') return '';
    var d = new Date(serial * 1000);

    function pad(digit) {
      return (digit < 10 ? '0' : '') + digit.toString();
    }
    // getMonth is zero-based, getDate() isn't. So far for consistency
    return d.getUTCFullYear().toString() + '-' + pad(d.getUTCMonth() + 1) + '-' + pad(d.getUTCDate());
  }

  function buildSiteRow(site) {

    function buildCell(text) {
      var td = document.createElement('td');
      td.textContent = text;
      return td;
    }
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    tr.setAttribute('id', site.api_site_parameter);
    tr.appendChild(buildCell(makeHtml(site.name)));
    tr.appendChild(buildCell(formatDate(site.closed_beta_date)));
    tr.appendChild(buildCell(formatDate(site.open_beta_date)));
    tr.appendChild(buildCell(formatDate(site.launch_date)));
    return tr;
  }

  function appendSite(site) {
    document.getElementById('sites').appendChild(buildSiteRow(site));
  }

  function getInfo(site) {
    var id = site;
    callApi(
      'info', {
        site: site,
        filter: '!mr5-qoE)yP'
      }).then((items) => {
      if (items) {
        items.forEach((ri) => {
          console.log(id, ri.total_users);
          appendInfoRow(ri, id);
        });
      }
    });
  }

  var page = 1;

  function load() {
    var ldbtn = document.getElementById('load');
    ldbtn.disabled = true;
    getSites(page).then((sites) => {
      if (sites && sites.length > 0) {
        page++;
        sites.forEach((site) => {
          var id = site.api_site_parameter;
          if (site.site_type === 'main_site') {
            appendSite(site);
            getInfo(id);
          }
        });
        ldbtn.style.display = 'block';
        ldbtn.disabled = false;
      } else {
        ldbtn.style.display = 'none';
      }
    });
  }

  document.getElementById('load').addEventListener('click', load);
  load();

})();
```

```css
td:nth-child(5) {
  text-align: right;
}

td:nth-child(6) {
  text-align: right;
}

td:nth-child(7) {
  text-align: right;
}

#load {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@stackoverflow/stacks/dist/css/stacks.min.css">
<div id='error'></div>
<table class="s-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>closed beta</th>
      <th>open beta</th>
      <th>launch</th>
      <th>Q</th>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>Users</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id='sites'></tbody>
</table>
<button id='load'>Load ...</button>
```

Comment: The months and dates in the above list seem to be off by one from the dates retrieved from the API. They should be one more than the dates listed there. As examples, SO began beta 2008-07-31, but your list shows it as 2008-06-30, and Server Fault was launched 2009-05-26 but shows as 2009-04-25. Looking through the API output, this seems to affect all the dates.

Comment: @SonictheCuriouserHedgehog that is not the first time I forgot that  getMonth is zero-based. Utterly confusing. Many unicorns died, I'm sorry.

Comment: @SonictheCuriouserHedgehog [getDate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate) *An integer number, between 1 and 31, representing the day of the month for the given date according to local time.* [getMonth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth) *An integer number, between 0 and 11, representing the month in the given date according to local time. 0 corresponds to January, 1 to February, and so on.*

Comment: The dates are still off by one. SO shows up as 2008-07-30 when it should be 2008-07-31, and SF shows up as 2009-05-25 when it should be 2009-05-26 per the API (as well as checking the date the Community user "joined" the respective sites, which is the date the site was created).

Comment: Huh, the dates seem to be off by one *only* for the Trilogy sites, and they seem to be correct for the other sites. May have something to do with the fact that those sites' times from the API are 00:00 UTC, while the others all have nonzero times (usually 19:00 UTC).

Comment: @SonictheCuriouserHedgehog I needed to get/force the UTC time instead of local time. Now fixed.